# disable web.config generation for asp.net core 3.1 project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

The `dotnet publish` command for my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project creates a `web.config` file in my `publish/` directory. I don't want this file to be generated (or copied to that folder, at least) - it is never to be used with IIS at all.

When I took a look at the command output with verbosity increased, I found the following text:

```
   Target "_TransformWebConfig" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets" from project "C:\repos\reportweb\reportweb\reportweb.csproj" (target "_AspNetCoreProjectSystemPostPublish" depends on it):
       Using "TransformWebConfig" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\..\tools\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll".
       Task "TransformWebConfig"
         Configuring the following project for use with IIS: 'C:\repos\reportweb\reportweb\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\linux-x64\publish\'
         Updating web.config at 'C:\repos\reportweb\reportweb\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\linux-x64\publish\web.config'
         Configuring project completed successfully
       Done executing task "TransformWebConfig".
   Done building target "_TransformWebConfig" in project "reportweb.csproj".
```

Is it somehow possible to configure my project to skip the `_TransformWebConfig` Target or `TransformWebConfig` Task - or to use another way to skip the generation? I know I could make MSBuild delete the file afterwards, but having this disabled seems less *hacky* to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control this with the [`IsWebConfigTransformDisabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-3.1#prevent-webconfig-transformation) MSBuild property:

> To prevent transformations of the web.config file, set the MSBuild property `$(IsWebConfigTransformDisabled)`:
>
> ```
> dotnet publish /p:IsWebConfigTransformDisabled=true
> ```

Because this is an MSBuild property, you can also set it in the .csproj, instead of passing it as a command-line argument:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsWebConfigTransformDisabled>true</IsWebConfigTransformDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```